# Index syntax in Java equivalent to [1:]

Tags: java, python

In python, you can do `arr[1:]` which means from index 1 to end. Is there an equivalent in Java?

The closest I can think of is

```
for (int i : arr.length) {
   ...
}
```

But that doesn't iterate through the array within the input of a java array (`arr[]`)

Comment: Do Python arrays start at one or zero?

Comment: 0 but you can start at index 1 if you do [1:]

Comment: I guess `arr[1:]` starts from 1 and `arr[0:]` stars from 0 @markspace

Comment: OK, no Java doesn't have this without using an index or some other sort of code.  I think lambdas/streams can do this in Java 8, but it's still fairly verbose.  AntonH have you the best answer: gotta loop over it with an index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `arr[1:]` returns a copy of the array `arr` where you get all elements from index 1 to the end, use

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length);
```

Comment: What if I had a custom array? ex: `TreeNode[]`

Comment: replace arr with the name of my TreeNode[]?

Comment: @Liondancer There's an overloaded method for reference types.

Comment: This is close, but it does **copy** the array.  A little ineffcient, but if you prefer brevity to speed then it works fine.  Be aware that it will throw errors if the start index is greater than the original's length.

Comment: @user2357112, does Python throw an error if the 1 is past the end of the array?

Comment: @user2357112: ok then, watch the Java version above.  It's different and will throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use an index:

```
for (int i=1 ; i<arr.length ; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Using the enhanced `for` loop (`for (int i : arr) {...}`) goes through the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head the array must implement a collection for the enhanced loop to work

```
for (int i : arr) {}

// syntax
for (DataType identifier : arrayIdentifier) {}
```

Comment: This would go through the whole array, which isn't what OP is asking for.

Comment: @AntonH if he wants to iterate over a specific index, then clearly a loop with index will be better e.g. your example. but the syntax that he wrote was that of an enhanced loop which i corrected with the proper syntax.

Comment: In the first line of his post, he asks how to go through the array from a specific index. He gave what he found, ie the enhanced for loop, and asks if it's okay, which it isn't.

Comment: @AntonH And that's the problem with other programming languages, you learn bad habits using "cool gimmicks".